# while updating to 16.04 my pc got stuck

Tags: 16.04, restart

After updating to 16.04 LTS i'm unable  to shutdown or restart my pc. Only terminal and files i'm able access.

Comment: Please add more information. What does it hang on?

Answer (score 0):

for shutdown and restart your pc in terminal use : telinit 0  and telinit 6 ,respectively.

```
telinit 0

telinit 6
```

Comment: Sorry I already reverted to 14.04 os